# `setup.py develop` works but `pip install -e` doesn't - TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, pytest, setuptools

[Setuptools](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/development_mode.html) deprecated `develop` in favor of `-e`, yet former works for me while latter gives

```py
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

for `MyClass()` that comes from `from my_pkg import MyClass`, with `__init__.py` being

```py
from .myclass import MyClass
```

All I found is a bunch of closed and stale issues that point to [this issue](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/230).

- This problem is *not* consistently reproducible: copying all files and just renaming the library can be a fix, or (though I can no longer reproduce) reinstalling.
- This problem *was* reproducible via plain terminal `python`, but now it's only reproducible via `pytest tests/` and inside of `test_example()` that's inside of `tests/test_stuff.py`. If I just put `MyClass()` outside of `test_example()`, it doesn't fail...
- I'm using an Anaconda virtual environment with a mix of pip and conda installs that otherwise works fine.
- I'm using `pyproject.toml` with `requires`, and a rather basic `setuptools.setup`
- `warnings.warn(MyClass)` gives `<module 'my_pkg.MyClass' from '../my_pkg/MyClass/__init__.py'>`; this file doesn't exist.

Is this a known issue with known possible causes? Unsure how to debug it as I can't even reproduce it in a near-clone. I've tried

```
conda clean --all
pip cache remove *
pip cache purge
```

Python 3.10.4, Windows 10, setuptools 65.5.0, pytest 7.2.0.

Answer (score -1):

[pip uninstall not working with editable dependencies](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5193), had to remove manually from `site-packages`.